# Форматирование текста в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, форматирование

Делаю что-то похожее на текстовый редактор. Нужно реализовать форматирование текста (жирный, курсив, подчеркивание). Могут быть выбраны как один компонент так и все сразу. Стиль применяться должен ко всему тексту в editText. Сервер ждет от меня Html.

Я сделал popupMenu в котором указал пункты жирный, курсив и подчеркнутый. Как мне реализовать формирования html путем нажатия на пункты меню?

P.S. пытался засунуть теги html в ресурсы, но теги в ресурсах студия не воспринимает. также пытался через TextWatcher но успеха не добился(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте три переменные

```
boolean boldEnabled, italicEnabled, underlineEnabled;
```

Создайте три кнопки-переключателя режимов текста и в слушателе реализуйте логику триггера, например, для кнопки жирного текста

```
boldEnabled = !boldEnabled;
```

Создайте метод для обновления режимов текста

```
public void refresh() {
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
if(boldEnabled && italicEnabled) editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
else if(boldEnabled) editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
else editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
if(underlineEnabled)
edittext.setPaintFlags(editText.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
}
```

И вызывайте этот метод во всех трёх слушателях кнопок-триггеров.